# Getting html element attribute is unreliable

Tags: html, attributes, dom-events, custom-data-attribute

So i am trying to get a data attribute of a div element but it is giving a null but not always; after like ten times of showing a null, it shows the attribute so what am i missing? is it a bug?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';


    function App() {

    const [toggleComments, setToggleComments] = useState(false);

    const changetoggleState = (e)=> { setToggleComments(toggleComments ? false : true);
      console.log(toggleComments); console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-comment-data'))};
    
    return <div data-comment-data="hello there" onClick={changetoggleState}>Hello World</div>
    
     };

    export default App;
```

Comment: could you provide the code?

Comment: I added the code.

Comment: your code doesn't show how you executing it, please provide a minimum reproducible code

Comment: I did, check it out.

Comment: The attribute is `data-comment-data` but you then try to access `data-commentdata`

Comment: it is a typo, still the same null.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
e.target.getAttribute("data-comment-data")
```

Online demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-paper-dsd1tt?file=/src/App.js:305-347

Comment: i did, nothing changed. i am still getting a null :(

Comment: Are you sure?! check the online link. This code work fine!

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was i put the data attribute on the div but when i was clicking for some reason i was clicking on a PNG icon inside the div that did not have any data attribute. that is why it sometimes worked when i did not click on the PNG.